# Selectors, toggle if any list item clicked

Tags: jquery

I created a menu,

```
 <div class="topParent">
            <div id="child-1" class="child action-1"></div>
            <div id="child-2" class="menu">
                <ul id="list-1"></ul>
            </div>

            <div id="child-3" class="child action-2"></div>
            <div id="child-4" class="menu">
                <ul id="list-2"></ul>
            </div>
            <div id="child-5" class="child action-3"></div>
        </div>
```

Now I want if anyone clicks on any of list item within "topParent" div then call a function.

I am confused with selectors which is why asking for help.

`$("#Parent li").click` ? would this going to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(".topParent li").click(function() {
});
```

There is no `li` in your `html markup`, if you are adding `li` dynamically then try this:

```
$(".topParent").on('click', 'li', function() {
});
```

Comment: I dont see any `li` elements in the markup. Please read code carefully

Answer (score 0):

First off the `.` is for class' and `#` is for Id's.

So I would do it a bit like *Manoj Yadav*

```
$('.topParent').on('click', '.menu li', function(){
   // function for when li items is clicked
}).on('click', '.child', function(){
   // For when the div's with class child is clicked if you want something special to happen here..
});
```

This way I can have separate functions depending on which element is clicked..